# Why do I get a NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Here is my code...

```
 import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test extends JFrame {
    public test() {     
        setSize(1000,600);
    }

    private static JButton[] remove;
    private static JPanel p = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame t = new test();
        remove = new JButton[25];
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) { 
            remove[i].setBounds(243, 92 + 30 * i, 85, 20);
        }
    t.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I created an array that consists of 25 buttons but why is it still throwing this error :S?

Comment: Because you don't actually *have* any buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your line:

```
remove = new JButton[25];
```

Your are creating an array with 25 slots for JButton objects. You must now create every JButton you want to place into the array.

```
for(int i= 0; i < 25; i++) {
   remove[i] = new JButton();
}
```

After that, when you attempt to access an array element, you will be accessing one of your previously created JButtons directly.

Before that, your created array contains only null elements and when you try to access one of your array slots it is as if you were trying to ask a null reference to do something, which is not possible and that's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: so this leads to the next question...  I've already set it Visible, but I still can't see no buttons :((  Is there anything wrong wif my code :S  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1447864 In your for loop, call `t.add(remove[i])`.

Comment: yeaaa i just noticed thanks a lot im just so stupid and careless :(((

Comment: The panel is not necessary as one is already contained within the JFrame, however you need to set the layout manager of the frame and also add the buttons to the frame.

Answer (score 1):

with this `remove = new JButton[25]` you just create `buttons-array` with 25 items capacity but your array is empty. so you have to first create new `Button` and then you can set `setBounds(243, 92 + 30 * i, 85, 20)` for each.

```
remove = new JButton[25];
for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
   remove[i] = new JButton();
   remove[i].setBounds(243,92+30*i,85,20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All references that are not initialized to point to an object on the heap are set equal to null.

Try this:

```
    // Ever heard of "magic numbers"?  These are very bad, indeed.
    // Your snippet is loaded with them.
    remove = new JButton[25];
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
        remove[i] = new JButton();
        remove[i].setBounds(243,92+30*i,85,20);
    }
```